# Static .gif image not displaying in IE11 but is displaying in Chrome and FF

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, browser, internet-explorer-11, gif

I have a web application that is supposed to display a user's profile image and allow them to upload a new profile picture. The supported files are .jpg, .gif, .bmp. If I load the application in Chrome or Firefox and upload a .gif image, the images load properly but in Internet Explorer, it doesn't load at all. If I type in the file location of the .gif image directly in the browser in IE11, it displays the image.

I'm not sure if it's a browser or application issue. The below screenshot is what displays in place of the .gif image:

[image: .gif]

This is the code that checks for the correct file extension and file size:

```
 protected void btnUploadPhoto_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Get filename and extention
        string fileName = flUploadPhoto.PostedFile.FileName.Remove(0, flUploadPhoto.PostedFile.FileName.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
        string fileExtention = fileName.Remove(0, fileName.LastIndexOf(".") + 1);
        int fileSize = (flUploadPhoto.PostedFile.ContentLength / 1024);

        //Check file extention
        if (fileExtention.ToLower() == "jpg" || fileExtention.ToLower() == "gif" || fileExtention.ToLower() == "bmp")
        {
            //Check Image file size
            if (fileSize <= 300)
            {
                //Get image stream
                Stream imgStream = flUploadPhoto.PostedFile.InputStream;
                int imgLen = flUploadPhoto.PostedFile.ContentLength;
                string imgContentType = flUploadPhoto.PostedFile.ContentType;
                byte[] imgBinaryData = new byte[imgLen];
                int n = imgStream.Read(imgBinaryData, 0, imgLen);

                //Upload document
                SelfServicePortal.UpdateSelfServiceEmployeePhoto(hfEmployeeNumber.Value, imgBinaryData);

                //Refresh Employee Photo and parent page
                SelectEmployeePhoto();
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "RefreshParentPage", "fncRefreshParentPage('" + hfRefreshClientID.Value + "');", true);
            }
            else
            {
                //Alert incorrect file size
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "AlertIncorrectFileSize", "fncAlertIncorrectFileSize();", true);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Alert incorrect extention
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "AlertIncorrectExtention", "fncAlertIncorrectExtention();", true);
        }
    }
```

Front-end for the image:

```
 <div id="divImage" runat="server" class="thumbnail employee-profile-img" href="#" style="padding-right: 5px;">
                    <img runat="server" id="imgBC" class="navPortrait" />
                </div>
```

Comment: As I am not available with the code for the `SelfServicePortal.UpdateSelfServiceEmployeePhoto` and `SelectEmployeePhoto(); Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` methods I am not able to test your posted code. I try to create a sample that uploads and displays the image and I can see that GIF files loads properly in IE 11. [See my test result here.](https://imgur.com/a/eGNPEhN). I suggest you step by step debug your code may give some hint for the cause of the issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT can you please share the code you used to create your sample? Did you use a Stream?

Comment: My test code does not use stream and I just try to upload the file and save it to the folder and then try to display the file from the folder. I suggest you post a proper code example that we can try to run on our side to check for the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFTL I'm not sure what you mean by proper code example. This is the code that is currently implemented in the live system and it works on Chrome and Firefox as it should. I'm having issues with .gif images only in IE11. And it's with this specific code. There's no other code that is used to upload the photo.

Comment: Can you please inform us how do you display the uploaded image, If possible share that code. Try to check the browser console to see whether there is an error.